# Adding items to txt output in the same file from

Tags: r, sink

I would like to printout to the same txt (outfile.txt) file items one after the other. 
For instance, first I would like to print to outfile.txt a dataframe - u. Afterwards, a written message 'hello' and finally a summary of model.
How can I do it? Is `sink(outfile.txt)` is appropriate for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a **very bad idea** to mix data in the same file. I advise against it in the strongest terms: it makes the data file next to unusable for other programs.

That said, most functions to save data have an `append` argument. You can set this to `TRUE` to append to an existing file rather than overwriting its contents. No need for `sink`.

Where you *do* need `sink` (or equivalent) is when you want to write contents formatted in the same way as it’s written on the console. This, for instance, is the case for `summary`.

Here’s an example similar to your requirements:

```
filename = 'test.txt'
write.table(head(cars), filename, quote = FALSE, col.names = NA)
cat('\nHello\n\n', file = filename, append = TRUE)
capture.output(print(summary(cars)), file = filename, append = TRUE)
```

Rather than `sink`, this uses [`capture.output`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/capture.output.html), which is a convenience wrapper around `sink`.